# How can I make a different CSS for the first child <div>?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="columns clearfix">
   <div class="xl float-left gutter-right" 
        data-ng-show="modal.data.createdDate">
        <span class="label">Created</span>
        <input class="full-width"  type="text" value="{{modal.data.createdDate }}" />
   </div>
   <div class="xl float-left" 
        data-ng-show="modal.data.modifiedDate">
        <span class="label">Modified</span>
        <input class="full-width" type="text" value="{{modal.data.modifiedDate }}"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am looking for a way to simplify this HTML with some CSS. Can someone tell me how I could remove the gutter-right and inline and make it so that this is introduced with a class in the top-level `<div>`? Somehow I want to specify gutter-right but just have it for the first inside `<div>`. Note I am using IE9 browsers and above. Also if it's possible I would like to have it so I don't need to specify the `span.label` and the `input.full-width`.

Note the reason I am trying to do this is because I have many fields set up like that with two fields on a row and a label above each field.

CSS:

```css
.float-left {
   float: left;
}
.gutter-right {
   margin-right: 2rem;
}
.form label, .form .label {
   display: block;
   margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
.full-width {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Like `.gutter-right:first-child`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `element:nth-child(1){ /*whatever*/ }`

or `element:first-child { /*whatever*/ }`

You can also use `element:nth-of-type(1){ /*whatever*/ }`

Comment: Hmm the bit that you just added doesn't quite make sense. If there's more than one element then how does `:nth-of-type(1)` differ from the other two in getting the first element?

Comment: Bear in mind that `first-child()` is supported in IE 7 and 8, `nth-child()` isn't

Comment: @BoltClock It doesn't differ from the first two, I just worded it awfully... I was just giving them more suggestions sorry.

Comment: @Matt Maclennan: Does it matter? The OP is only looking to support IE9 anyway.

Comment: @BoltClock true, just mentioning the drawbacks of using `nth-child()` for future reference, and for anyone viewing this later :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `E:first-child` css selector.

The `:first-child` selector is used to select the specified selector, only if it is the first child of its parent.

[Example](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstchild/demo)

[List of CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a rule for `.gutter-right`, go for `.xl:first-child`:

```
.xl:first-child {
   margin-right: 2rem;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z45wA/1/) [`first-child` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child)